# Is there something wrong with DatePicker's MinDate?

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker, android-calendar

When I set:

```
datePicker.datePicker.minDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

My layout looks wrong, with the date being shown on top of my Calendar:

[image]
[image]

I've tried setting **maxDate**, and not setting a condition at all and it shows the layouts as it should be.
The problem is on **minDate**

Answer (score 0):

```
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);  
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);  
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL,this,year, month, day);  

    //Get the DatePicker instance from DatePickerDialog  
    DatePicker dp = dpd.getDatePicker();  
    //Set the DatePicker minimum date selection to current date  
    dp.setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());//get the current day  
    //dp.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);// Alternate way to get the current day  

    //Add 6 days with current date  
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,6);  

    //Set the maximum date to select from DatePickerDialog  
    dp.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());  
    //Now DatePickerDialog have 7 days range to get selection any one from those dates
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
 val now = Calendar.getInstance()
 val datePickerDialog = com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
               activity,
                now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
 datePickerDialog.setMinDate(cal)
```

Comment: This implementation would be good, but it uses an external library as the datepicker. I wanted to use the one that Android Studio provides. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, this should solve your problem

```
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog toDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Record_Sample_Collection_Details.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);                                                       
    }

}, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

toDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
```